# Simple QR reader with Django backend. Is PhoneGap suitable?

Tags: android, mysql, django, cordova

I'm working on a website built with Django that sells concert tickets with a QR on them. And I want to make an Android/iOS app thats reads that QR code and validates the tickets reading from the MySQL database stored on the server.

Basically, I need:

1. Read QR code
2. Send data to server
3. Receive data from server (e.g.: a boolean variable)

I've search different aproaches and found PhoneGap, but I'm not sure if this would be the best way. I also found Kivy, but it seems to be rather old and not updated anymore.

I do not have Android or Java knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the kivy devs here :)

Kivy is being actively developped, with commits everyday, by multiple contributors. It's true, though, that we didn't have a release in more than 6 months, but we are working that to achieve that soon.

What you want is possible with kivy, in fact, her is an example that does pretty much that, done by kivy lead dev some time ago https://github.com/tito/android-zbar-qrcode it uses a java lib and other android specific things to efficiently capture/display the stream, but it's well integrated in the kivy app. If you were to chose the kivy way, this should save you a lot of time :).

Comment: Is there any way to use in a kivy app desktop? or just for android platform?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is the best solutions for your case.
If don't want them you can make a native Android apps that use REST service to send and receive data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Basic4Android. It's the simplest way imaginable to make android apps. It has a ton of libraries for anything imaginable, including android L support, json, mysql, etc.

You can use your own android device for testing and can do **hot code swap**. Basically changing your code while your app runs and see the changes immediately. It has a design panel, similar to visual studio's xaml. Similar, as in you can drag stuff around and you can code values.

It produces native code (no vebview hybrids here). 
There's a free trial, of course. (and the price is ridiculously low).

While I understand this dosen't answer your question exactly, I am 100% sure you'll love this tool.